# Is there an appropriate filesystem to store many duplicate files?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, version-control

I have a bunch of different versions of source codes to manage and have to store them locally.
So, here comes the problem: How may I store them without using too much disk space?

I am not using version control system on them, because there are too many branches for each market and each big or small release, and more importantly I want keep them usable at anytime (without using some scripts to get a version from the library).

Comment: this is the consequence:    git seems not that hard.. I am living well with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- NTFS supports [single-instance storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Single_Instance_Storage_.28SIS.29). However, this is only available on Server versions of Windows.
- You could set up a Linux server with *lessfs* or *opendedup*, and access it over Windows File Sharing.
- "Too many branches" shouldn't be a problem with modern VCSs such as Git.
- Or buy a bigger HD.

Comment: OpenDedup also works on Windows now. might be useful.